# How to generate RSDF,CCF,DLC,CNL2 files in PHP?

Tags: php, containers

Anyone have any idea about how i could generate rsdf, ccf, dlc or cnl2 files in PHP?
Basically i have a link and i need to generate these file containers and offer for download, is there any php library the i can use for that?

Answer (score 0):

There is an API provided by JDownloader that lets you create RSDF, CCF and DLC containers. You can find it [here](http://jdownloader.org/knowledge/wiki/linkprotection/container/dlcapi?s=lng_en).